# Textual resolution of [Current User] and [Me]

Tags: list-view, filter

In a list-view filter, I think I want to use either `[Me]` or `[Current User]`.

I can't find a list of possible filter variables with their possible resolutions anywhere (Sharepoint Server 2010).

What values do these resolve to?  That is, does me return a text value of `Doe, John` or `Doe,John` or `John Doe` or `Mr. John Doe`?

I am interested in the same information for `[Me]`.  Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: can i have a variable returns the user name without the domain suffix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is:

```
[Me] = domain\username
```

It is returned as the login name with the domain prefixed.

Answer (score 2):

The [Me] reference is a type of function in SharePoint / Office. Use the following link to see the official documentation on Formulas and Functions. This isn't exactly the side-by-side comparison you are looking for but, it does detail things fairly well.

Specifically speaking, if you go into **Information | Me Function** you will see what they have listed to explain how [Me] works. They explain that "...returns the current user name." as well.

Comment: I understand that it returns the "current user name" - my question is: what is the format?  What does it look like when it gets returned.  Your link doesn't help me any here.

Comment: @BGM Should be DOMAIN\username. :)

Comment: Say, could you propose that as an answer?

Comment: "Use the following link to see the official documentation..." - where is this link you speak of?
EDIT: I see now that it was removed because the link died. I believe that makes this answer no longer an answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Me] is most of time used in making views when we to filter items So that user can not view others data, i.e.

Here is a link to [official documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/client/15/serverhelp/preview?AssetId=HA102771361&lcid=1033&products=WSSENDUSER&queryid=&respos=1&HelpID=filtering#_Toc346115851)

[image: list-view filter]

Comment: That's nice information, but it is not an answer to the question.  Can you add something to make this an answer?