# Can someone spot the error please

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, approval

I am trying ti create a calculated column where it will add the vale "has been completed" if the approval column is approved. Below are the code and screenshot of the error.

Thank you

```
    =IF([Approval Status]="Approved","has been completed")
```

[image]

Comment: Similar question already exists. Please see, it will help you: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/79557/why-cant-i-get-this-calculated-field-to-work

Comment: If Approval Status is NOT listed when you edit the Formula, you can not use it. Becuase it is a SharePoint internal field (same applies to Created By and some other fields)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a FALSE clause as third IF parameter but that is no error, should default to FALSE.

Most likely you need the ; (semi-colon) as separator and not a , (comma)

Comment: Thanks, Danny, But when I put semicolon says 'you have a syntax error in the formula'.

Comment: So add the False output