# Filtering on username doesn't give unique users

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, filter

I have a list where I'm able to sort on different parameters. One such useful parameter is the currently logged in user, like a "My Tasks" kind of thing.

But the problem is that if there's another user in the system with the same name as me, I also get his/her tasks as well. What would be a good way to filter to make sure I actually only get *my* tasks, even though other users might share my name?

Comment: Are you using the `[Me]` filter?

Comment: Yes I am. I'm not sure if I'm using it wrong (is that even possible?) or if there's a bug somewhere, because if my name is 'John Doe' and I filter on [Me], I get all users with the name 'John Doe'.

Comment: This seems to suggest it should return `Domain\userName` http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74470/textual-resolution-of-current-user-and-me , but doesn't seem to be correct in your case!